# communication via ultrasound

Tags: modulation, ultrasound, demodulation, transducer

I want to communicate simple requests and ids over ultrasound.

To do this I need to modulate a message onto a 40kHz carrier to drive a ultrasound transducer.

[Here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDsB0AcYCYCsBTAtJEAGaZJllgDYBOZWBWEgZkqKgRCRABZqAoAE3CKx7+T0wvEI04oAZgEMArgBsALuwDGopEJGDRWWNnDoSIatBaRYbBPkTUi1PEXYB3NRr60+wvlicvtu937Y7ADmvgg6YQgsQc4BnkZEuvHeAE4JSSI2uuG6Hlj53qFZgcUIUUFSrPngLNG1SbUgScxoYMxgBQVGJmbUJJBkkMiQWCzMxqbmtFYINnaQQp3esYn8VR4iy+vglOk7uT7FiP6rJPRbxWesLLpXW-UgVw9gjanXDdFIiDXReQUqTG+L0+3xyehYBlEJiIbBYHSQJCwkHw+EOqzBX0YYO8lXUHl2MPxumaIFa7SWAmhbGEcIRYGoWDABChLBh1DhWARSJREA6nR8mJ+TBEwJiwo83zxIBhYqlMsJ0t+PgV8pYRIqio8jSGWuihmYf06UOYCCpdhhbRI9MZzL5-wASpq1kRyslwZSDXocEgQgwBBEdaI1UEAA5+oWBsEQLw+NCUXRStBw+hSrZxwiAxjphObWPJzOk-Op2NlT6NNAKpCvEvlFhXOPlKtK5xJ2B8Ov0CvBjti1tuGyFttGcy9+NGAd98fnEsZ6gj7NT0flAJJ4RGcJL6Jz6INrcbtP57eFtcBNOCtV8Lvt6pn77UJBZ8832NgMhGB+kwX3xhp1+MC+kn+74-rGR4PFe7y9mB1RoGBNxQRuAGwSOAEHmu+arvQNwxi22GsGumH4dOLZjhhpZEaOGZ4Qu+beAopLkT2NF3OAhZwDCdamMIRBILA1CYEm0AkBQSKWJyyIUCOfLsPRsGITBpE3qxgkkKpdavpAXx1nOyBsWcbD9JAdjIAZhjSbJQFIYxSnRtAWCUFEVazOyLpYGQpjYHZ968GUiSQGMvBMtQ4D5DJg7tvW+Y9h4nmMgMliUNhPGvnYsV4IMCAkCwZR4G094hXRpLQZeUU2XpKJVkgCw8fxVqfnZ8D9FVmVmCQXwFWFaBPiVQ6oaxOAFEgOj2TcQ1EHgrLfGgA2NZpQz9FQQ2qcF0kAG6kgq4GbUp-5Gp6XjQD6ACWx4piIhG8LkaW+hdEQXeUbyTmCk7HHodrsGkhFAUm8GvYa7CVEmMqvUDe5NOALRtAVRrTXZlhEP5Lr0ogTaZVmA2WPgMJDAsAxubsdqhZ9eEg02+xvf8oRdY0pMirsB6-bsX30x9p3k4RtBvUN-y4SeWasmD3gIFN+ZaEm1RaAIogAFQABRSGgABGACUoEbmL+ZAWmARjk9ERofQuuHvueZrhrQ7UAObxxJk6v69D3jrRBZMQdFogO0wXqeT6vP0Jz8TJOwAD2aj9fhZSezg0asQAIigAC2QecPIR0oCkSgh0g7Tuqpkd2QU-Q8S62eMFnRhVAA1gAEgAXgAOgAzgAKikAAnwRp8HDBh2qucdLFBcLOoulYt3K1YNX9cNwAkgAdiGMgZ570e92ZB0FGYKPlxATepxIIZSA3Ddd0ZPdufqaW6dEEAALJJynadL7aOcXwNg9F7pJrgP4IAxzIKTKAABYNyAbPI6CglBAA) you can find a simulation of what I am trying with a gilbert cell for modulation a difference amplifier as a driver for the transducer (not shown in the simulation) and an OOK demodulator consisting of a LP, an average detector and a comparator.

- Is the difference amplifier (with +-50V as supply) sufficient as a driver for the
  [transducer](https://www.ekulit.de/wp-content/uploads/datasheets/700620%20A-18P20.pdf) and can I also use it for the other end to amplify
  the received signal ?
- If it is sufficient which HiV op amp would you recommend ?
- Do you see any other design flaws ?

Comment: You might consider adapting a ranging circuit.  And use FSK, not OOK.

Comment: Depending on what you want to transmit, you might hack IR remote circuits. They use a 38 kHz carrier ... pretty sure they inherited that from ultrasonic remotes in the 1970s before IR LEDs and photodiodes became available.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what is the output there on your simulation, kind a weird circuit. If the output is square pulse, you don't need an opamp, just two transistors like D-class amplifier. Such HV opamps do exist, also with DC/DC converters on board. Look for Apex HV opamp board. They also make PWM amplifiers.

You could also DIY it from discrete components, but I do think you need something that works out of box with good documentation.

[image]

[image]